# NoClassDefFoundError: class sun.awt.image.ByteInterleavedRaster

Tags: java, exception, awt, noclassdeffounderror

I am getting an error:

```
NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class sun.awt.image.ByteInterleavedRaster
```

**What I am trying to achieve?**

I am generating a PDF file using iText that calls the getHeader method that sets a header logo to the PDf file.

Suddenly, I am facing the following exception & I have no idea what it is referring to.

**exception**

```
javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class sun.awt.image.ByteInterleavedRaster
    org.apache.struts.actions.DispatchAction.dispatchMethod(DispatchAction.java:295)
    org.apache.struts.actions.DispatchAction.execute(DispatchAction.java:170)
    org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.processActionPerform(RequestProcessor.java:425)
    org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.process(RequestProcessor.java:228)
    org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.process(ActionServlet.java:1913)
    org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.doPost(ActionServlet.java:462)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:647)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
```

**root cause**

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class sun.awt.image.ByteInterleavedRaster
    java.awt.image.Raster.createWritableRaster(Raster.java:980)
    java.awt.image.Raster.createWritableRaster(Raster.java:941)
    javax.imageio.ImageTypeSpecifier.createBufferedImage(ImageTypeSpecifier.java:1073)
    javax.imageio.ImageReader.getDestination(ImageReader.java:2896)
    com.sun.imageio.plugins.png.PNGImageReader.readImage(PNGImageReader.java:1280)
    com.sun.imageio.plugins.png.PNGImageReader.read(PNGImageReader.java:1577)
    javax.imageio.ImageIO.read(ImageIO.java:1448)
    javax.imageio.ImageIO.read(ImageIO.java:1308)
    com.appraisal.utility.Methods.getHeader(Methods.java:498)
    com.appraisal.process.ReviewLetterAction.viewletter(ReviewLetterAction.java:1276)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    org.apache.struts.actions.DispatchAction.dispatchMethod(DispatchAction.java:269)
    org.apache.struts.actions.DispatchAction.execute(DispatchAction.java:170)
    org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.processActionPerform(RequestProcessor.java:425)
    org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.process(RequestProcessor.java:228)
    org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.process(ActionServlet.java:1913)
    org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.doPost(ActionServlet.java:462)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:647)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
```

Comment: please provide a [mcve]

Comment: I agree with @JimHawkins about the MCVE - would be helpful in sorting the problem. OTOH I note that the app. is a servlet. Is the server running in headless mode?

Comment: BTW - See [What is a stack trace, and how can I use it to debug my application errors?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3988788/418556)